# How to use datastore to save non-leaderstat values?(Roblox Studio)

Tags: user-interface, lua, game-engine, roblox, datastore

I am trying to make a clicker game, and I want to be able to datastore the Image of the clicker and the value of it (How much clicking the button gives) but no matter what even though the default is 1 every time I leave and rejoin it's two even if  I change the value to 10. I also know that it's not the default value because it does not print in output the "Assigning default value".
My understanding of datastore is shaky. Any help is appreciated!

```
function PlayerAdded(player)
    
    local clickValue = Instance.new("IntValue")
    clickValue.Name = "clickValue"
    clickValue.Parent = player

    local clickerImage = Instance.new("StringValue")
    clickerImage.Name = "clickerImage"
    clickerImage.Value = "rbxassetid://284663799"
    clickerImage.Parent = player
    
    
    
    local success = nil
    local playerData = nil
    local attempt = 1
    repeat
        success, playerData = pcall(function()
            return dataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
        end)
        attempt +=1
        if not success then
            warn(playerData)
            task.wait(3)
        end
        
    until success or attempt == 5
    if success then
        print("Connected to database")
        if not playerData then
            print("Assigning default data")
            playerData ={
                ["clickWorth"] = 1,
                ["ImageTexture"] = "rbxassetid://284663799"
                    
            }
        end
        sessionData[player.UserId] = playerData
        
    else
        warn("Unable to get data for", player.UserId)
        player:Kick("Unable to load you data.Try again later")
    end
    clickValue.Value = sessionData[player.UserId].clickWorth
    clickerImage.Value = sessionData[player.UserId].ImageTexture

    clickValue.Changed:Connect(function()
        sessionData[player.UserId].clickWorth = clickValue.Value
        
    end)
    clickerImage.Changed:Connect(function()
        
        sessionData[player.UserId].ImageTexture = clickerImage.Value
    end)
        

    
end





function PlayerLeaving(player)
    if sessionData[player.UserId] then
        local success = nil
        local errorMsg = nil
        local attempt = 1
        
        repeat
            success, errorMsg = pcall(function()
                local clickValue = player.clickValue
                local clickerImage = player.clickerImage
                clickValue.Value = sessionData[player.UserId].clickWorth
                
            dataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, sessionData[player.UserId])
            end)
            attempt +=1
            if not success then
                warn(errorMsg)
                task.wait(3)
            end
        until success or attempt == 5
        if success then
            print("Data saved for", player.Name)
        else
            warn("Unable to save for", player.Name)
        end
    end
        
    end
```

I got most of this code from watching a Yt video.

Comment: Does anything call the `PlayerLeaving` function?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was being dumb... I made the ClickerImage asset In player Id after playing the game once so the datastore only had "Click Worth" in it and I could never assign ClickerImage because it didn't exist... All I had to do was rename the Datastore from "data" to something else. Lol, so sorry. Well at least ik that now.